# Hamburger menu or back button on Android?

Tags: navigation, material-design, android

Should I display hamburger menu icon (in the place of the navigation icon on the top App bar) on every screen that comes directly from the navigation drawer on Android or should it be the back button?

**EDIT** (as I cannot attach screenshots to comments)

@Levano, this is what I mean by "navigation icon" (which obviously might be a back or close button on some other screen):
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "navigation icon"?

Comment: @Levano, I answered by editing the original post

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The burger menu should be displayed on all of your top level destinations - the same screens that are listed in your navigation drawer.

When the user navigates to a deeper level, from one of these top level destinations, the burger menu will be replaced by either a back or close icon.

The back icon is typically used for view only screens, whereas the close icon is used for processes that can be discarded by means of the close icon (like create, add or edit).